# Opened a FancyBox Widget within a FancyBox Iframe and cant see data because of FancyBox Widget Width/Height=0

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii, fancybox

I have opened a `FancyBox Widget` within a `FancyBox Iframe`.

Within the FancyBox Iframe, I see all the data i wanted;

Now, when the FancyBox Widget appears, i can't set width and height;

How do I set the `Height and Width` of the FancyBox Widget?

This is how I initialise the FancyBox Iframe:

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array(
    'target' => 'a.referrallink',
    'id' => 'referrallink',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'iframe',
        'width' => 1000,
        'height' => 600,
    ),));
```

This is how I initialise the FancyBox Widget:

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array(
    'target' => 'a.fitGraphic',
    'id' => 'fitGraphic',
    'config' => array(
        'min-width' => 300,
        'min-height' => 300,
        'width'=>300,
        'height'=>300,
        'autoDimensions'=> true,
    ),));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
    $this->widget('application.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array(
        'target' => 'a.fitGraphic',
        'id' => 'fitGraphic',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'inline',
            'min-width' => '300px',
            'min-height' => '300px',
//            'height' => '300px',
//            'width' => '300px',
            'autoDimensions' => false,
        ),
            )
    );
```